# JAVA converting pounds to kilo, vice versa. action listener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

my program has a calculator layout, theres 9 buttons with clear , negative and convert. and 2 radio buttons that when you select one it converts the numbers you entered.
i have designed it, but im not sure how to do the action listener part.
i think  i just need help starting off the code .

```
// import packages
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


// class
public class Lab31Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

    // data declarations

    private JRadioButton k2pButton;
    private JRadioButton p2kButton;
    private ButtonGroup weight;
    private JPanel selectConversion;
    private JButton jb0,jb1,jb2,jb3,jb4,jb5,jb6,jb7,jb8,jb9,jbminus,jbclear,jbconvert;
    private JTextArea display;

    //constructor to initiate data and set up GUI
    public Lab31Panel()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        // organizing radio buttons and their behaviours
        k2pButton = new JRadioButton( "Kilograms to Pounds" );
        p2kButton = new JRadioButton( "Pounds to Kilograms" );
        weight = new ButtonGroup();
        weight.add( k2pButton );
        weight.add( p2kButton );


        // adding components to panel to be south of the GUI
        selectConversion = new JPanel();
        selectConversion.add( k2pButton );
        selectConversion.add( p2kButton );


        add( selectConversion, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

        //setting up west area of GUI
        JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel convert = new JPanel();

        // setting up components for the  west of the GUI
        westPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,3));
        westPanel.add(jb0 = new JButton("0"));
        westPanel.add(jb1 = new JButton("1"));
        westPanel.add(jb2 = new JButton("2"));
        westPanel.add(jb3 = new JButton("3"));
        westPanel.add(jb4 = new JButton("4"));
        westPanel.add(jb5 = new JButton("5"));
        westPanel.add(jb6 = new JButton("6"));
        westPanel.add(jb7 = new JButton("7"));
        westPanel.add(jb8 = new JButton("8"));
        westPanel.add(jb9 = new JButton("9"));
        westPanel.add(jbminus = new JButton("-"));
        westPanel.add(jbclear = new JButton("clear"));
        westPanel.add(jbconvert = new JButton("convert"));

        add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        //setting up east components
        JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();
        eastPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        display = new JTextArea();

        eastPanel.add(display,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(eastPanel);

        // add listeners to radio buttons
        p2kButton.addActionListener(this);
        k2pButton.addActionListener(this);



        //add listeners to all textfields

    } //end constructor

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {


    }
} // end class
```

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions:

- First and foremost, don't use the same ActionListener for all the buttons.
- In that vein, don't have your program implement ActionListener.
- Instead, create one ActionListener for the numeric buttons
- And one or perhaps better, three, for the operations buttons.
- In the numeric buttons, the code should be clear -- put the numbers into the display.
- In the operations button listeners, the actions will depend on which operation was pressed.
- If the convert button is pressed, then extract your numeric data from the field holding it,
- Convert text to number using a parsing method.
- Calculate your conversion
- And then display it.

## ALSO

- I would not add **any** ActionListener to the JRadioButtons since you really don't want any action to occur when pressed.
- Instead have the convert button's ActionListener check to see which JRadioButton is selected, and base the conversion equation on this selection.

---

Something like:

```
    // add listeners to radio buttons  // **** no, don't do this
    // p2kButton.addActionListener(this);
    // k2pButton.addActionListener(this);

    jbclear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO code to clear the JTextField
            // usually this will involve setText("")

        }
    });

    jbconvert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO code to convert
            // first get JRadioButton selection -- which one is set
            // then get data from text component
            // convert it to number (but catching for NumberFormatException)
            // do conversion based on the selected JRadioButton
            // and display usually with a call to setText(...)

        }
    });
```

Comment: at first it didnt work, but i put it inside the constructor Lab31Panel()
and removed the implements ActionListener from the main class